# Program that uses grayscale images to make transitions

Tags: video, editing, transitions

I remember some old video editing programs used a grayscale image to be used as a transition pattern.

Basically what they did was using the different levels of a grayscale image as a step for the transition.

Here is an example. Given the first image, when the program was analyzing the gray level marked with the red line as a threshold, the transition would look like the image below.

[image]

Do you know if that can be done in a free program like Davinci Resolve, Hit Film, probably Blender?

And a tip of how can be implemented?

<sub>images by pixabay</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a [Gradient Wipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI3v5TK4sYM) in Premiere Pro or a [Luma Fade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rp9re6HnXoM) in Davinci Resolve.

Just make sure your gradient image is a 3rd layer as long as your transition, and is selected as the 'gradient layer.'

(This should be a comment but I don't have enough karma to comment in this forum. Hope this helps :) )

Comment: No, in fact this is an answer, :o) Let me explore it and come back. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a solution to this using FFmpeg. There is a way to [merge two videos with a png mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467594/ffmpeg-add-alpha-channel-to-a-video-using-a-png-mask) and I'd assume it works with a video mask, but you'd still need a way to convert the single gradient image into an animated mask.